# Sum the minimum values in Maple

Tags: sum, minimum, maple

I have a list `A := [3,1,7,2,4,9]` in Maple.

How can I get the `n` minimum values?

I need to sum the `n` minimum values, so I guess I should use something like

```
n := 3:
A := [3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 9]:
add( [ seq( min( A ), i=1..n) ] );
```

but it will just sum `1 + 1 + 1`, since the minimum value is 1 every time. I need to remove the minimum value when it is first occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to first sort `A`.

```
restart;

A := [3,1,7,2,4,9]:
n := 3:

B := sort(A);
                       B := [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9]

add(B[i], i=1..n);
                                  6
```

What do you want to happen if some value occurs more than once?

[edited]
The followup question involved how `0` may be removed from a list. Here are few ways.

```
restart;

A := [3,1,0,7,2,0,4,0,9]:

remove(x->x=0, A);

                    [3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 9]

remove(type, A, identical(0));

                    [3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 9]

map(x->`if`(x=0,NULL,x), A);

                    [3, 1, 7, 2, 4, 9]
```

BTW, you didn't clarify what you wanted done when non-zero values occur more than once.

Comment: It will work, but is it possible to remove 0 from the list before sorting? I have tried `remove(0, A)`, but it doesn't work